# Show a pop up message onload

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom-events

The question is quote.html has a form on submit it goes to a PHP script and again through including same page in it and I want to show success pop up on second time.

My PHP script:

```
include'quote.html';
```

quote.html->php script->quote.html (this time show success message in pop up)

Detect that loads on PHP script and should show an pop up message.

Is this possible?

Comment: I didn't get it. What do you mean by "show a pop up of a html"

Comment: Please rewrite your question, I have no idea what you actually want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you redirect to php file script->quote.html file 
add request parameter in URL like
quote.html?pass=y

And after Adding below java script in quote.html file to detect Request variable

```
<script>
function get(name){
   if(name=(new RegExp('[?&]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
      return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
}
if(get('pass')=='y')
{
    //add your popup code 
}
</script>
```

Comment: please can u jsfiddle it am a newbee

Comment: @Maddy - I don't think you can reproduce this in jsFiddle...

Comment: sorry please if u down voted it take it  off and really thanks for the answer

Comment: i tried it but failed to reproduce the code can u give me an eloborated answer please